# SQL Server - query on getting DISTINCT records from a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, distinct

I have a table with out a PK on it, with 6 columns in it. I want to get distinct records based on only 5 columns and for the 6th column, any value from the non-distinct records.

[image]

For example, in the above set of data, I want to get distinct rows based on last 5 columns only and any value for the CreatedDate from the 5 rows (I dont care what the CreatedValue has, as long as it is from one of the 5 records). What are the options I have got?

Thanks
Vikram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should do it:

```
Select Max(CreatedDate), BusinessDate, BookId, DataTypeId, Version, DelFlag
From Table
Group By BusinessDate, BookId, DataTypeId, Version, DelFlag
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select BusinessDate, Bookid, DataTypeId, Version, DelFlag, min(CreatedDate)
    from YourTable
    group by BusinessDate, Bookid, DataTypeId, Version, DelFlag
```